# Is the number of high/low pressure regions different at low pressure levels at high pressure levels?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling

Is there a higher number of mid-latitude high/low pressure regions at 850 mb, as compared to the number of high/low pressure regions at 200 mb?

And if so, why?